# How to update a data table using a condition on the data within that data table?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, datatable

I am trying to put data into a data table based on a column value within that data table.

I am trying to do this by filling in 'homeDataTable' with all the data. Then add the rows from that data table into 'tempDataTable' where a column value = 1. Then i intend to set homeDataTable = tempDataTable so now the homeDataTable contains only data where the column value = 1.

Unfortunately i am hitting an Unhandled Exception everytime i try this that states "Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store the value."

I can't seem to get my For Each loop working that handles this, here is the code i currently have:

```
Public Shared Function LoadHomeDataSet()

Dim dp As New DataProxy

'Fill homeDataTAble
homeDataTable = dp.GetScheduledTasks

Dim tempDataTable As New SettingsDataSet.ScheduledTasksDataTable 
Dim tr As DataRow

'Attempt to add data into tempDataTable where SST_ACTIVE = 1
For Each tr In homeDataTable

  tempDataTable.Rows.Add(homeDataTable.Select("SST_ACTIVE = 1"))

Next

'Refresh the DataTable in the Home page with the current Task List
homeDataTable = tempDataTable
```

Just an FYI, homeDataTable is a Public Shared variable that is set with the following:

```
Public Shared homeDataTable As SettingsDataSet.ScheduledTasksDataTable
```

Note - as you can see, this is the same as tempDataTable.

Why is this not working? Is anyone able to please point me in the right direction? I feel like i am really close and just missing something stupid.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 4.8.03752.

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you want to filter Scheduled Tasks with `SST_ACTIVE = 1` (so you may just apply a filter) or do you want to actually remove Rows where `SST_ACTIVE <> 1`? (why is not `GetScheduledTasks()` doing that?) If the purpose is *presentation*, a filter is probably more efficient. -- `LoadHomeDataSet()` doesn't have a return value. Maybe it should return a DataTable.

Comment: @Jimi I want to remove the rows where SST_ACTIVE = 1 from homeDataTable but cannot change the Get SQL script to bring those in - i need to do it at the code level. The intention is that (later on) if the SST_ACTIVE = 1 then my application will run a SQL command stored in that same row.

Comment: `homeDataTable = homeDataTable.Select("SST_ACTIVE = 1").CopyToDataTable()`. In case you don't have the method, it's in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` assembly (which also provides `AsDataView()` and `AsEnumerable()`). -- Your Function should be a Function.

Comment: Or just `homeDataTable = dp.GetScheduledTasks().Select("SST_ACTIVE = 1").CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: @Jimi thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately they both give me a System.InvalidCastException error message. "Unable to cast object type of 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'ScheduledTasksDataTable". Any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, check what Type `ScheduledTasksDataTable` actually is. It appears it's not a DataTable type. Do you have some Entity Framework stuff going on there? Other ORM-ish things? Anyway, see what Types you have there and act accordingly.

Comment: @Jimi i got it mate. Thank you for your guidance. Im going to post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

With Jimi's guidance above, i was able to solve it with the following code. Turns out there was no need for a For Each loop:

```
Dim dp As New DataProxy
Dim tempDataTable As DataTable

'Fill homeDataTAble
homeDataTable = dp.GetScheduledTasks
tempDataTable = homeDataTable.Select("SST_ACTIVE = 1").CopyToDataTable()
homeDataTable = tempDataTable
```